# What is the gravitational constant in 5D?

Tags: general-relativity, dimensional-analysis, units, spacetime-dimensions, si-units

I am trying to find the energy density for a given spacetime using Einstein's Equation $G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$.  I am trying to do this in 5D and with restored SI units, but I am having trouble finding what the constant $\kappa$ should be.

I know that the Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$ should be in units of m$^{-2}$, and that in the 4D case the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ has units of energy density J m$^{-3}$.  I also know that in 4D $\kappa = \frac{8\pi G} {c^4}$, with units s$^2$kg$^{-1}$m$^{-1}$.  However, in 5D, the energy density will be given in units of J m$^{-4}$, so then $\kappa$ must be given in units of s$^2$kg$^{-1}$.  I'm not sure, then, what the value of $\kappa$ should be in 5D.

I have seen some papers and textbooks use $\kappa=\frac{8\pi G_5} {c^4}$, where $G_5$ is the "5D gravitational constant", but I can't seem to find what the 5D gravitational constant is meant to be, and none of these papers or textbooks seem to consider the problem of restoring to SI units.  I have also seen some papers and textbooks multiply the 4D $G$ by the length of the compactified 5th dimension, but I am looking at a case where the 5th dimension is not necessarily compactified.

What is Einstein's gravitational constant, $\kappa$, in 5D, for both the case of a compactified and a non-compactified 5th dimension?

Comment: Based on the relation
$M_\mathrm{Planck} = \left( \frac{\hbar^{d-3}}{G_\mathrm{N}^{(d)} c^{d-5}} \right)^{\frac{1}{d-2}}$ for the Planck mass in $d$ space-time dimensions, the graviational constant $G_\mathrm{N}^{(d)}$ has the SI units $\frac{\mathrm{m}^{d-1}}{\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{s}^2}$. This relation is equation $(4.8)$ in Ortin's Gravity and Strings book, $2$ed.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of a compactified 5th dimension, you can find your answer from [Kaluza-Klein dimensional reduction](https://pure.rug.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/14520848/c3.pdf):

> The D-dimensional gravitational constant is related to the (D+1)-dimensional one by the volume of the compact space $$\kappa^2_{D+1}=2\pi R_z\kappa^2_D$$

where $2\pi R_z$ is the volume of the compact dimension. In general, $$\kappa^2_{D+P}=V_P\cdot\kappa^2_D$$
I'm not an expert of large extra dimensions, but reading [some](https://doi.org/10.1142/S021773239900208X) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312161) on the subject it seems to me that a proper definition of $\kappa_5$ *is* part of the problem. I might be wrong on this last part though.